# How to read specific value from object array and add all values to one variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

All about my array:

```js
var list = []

function arrObject(name, coins, id) {
            this.name = name
            this.coins = coins
            this.id = id
            this.listed = function(){
                return (this.name + "" +"["+this.coins+"]")
            }
        }

list.push(new arrObject(user.username, coinsamount, user.id))
```

After adding two users my console.log output looks like:

```js
[
  {
    name: 'Mango',
    coins: '19',
    id: '454214634158999514',
    listed: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
[
  {
    name: 'Goodmg',
    coins: '41',
    id: '721805465937021781',
    listed: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
```

How can I take "coins" values and sum them to one variable?

EDIT.1 changed function from `Object` to `arrObject`

EDIT.2

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const embeds = require('./../../embeds.js')

var running = 0

module.exports = {
    commands: 'rjoin',
    minArgs: 1,
    maxArgs: 2,
    expectedArgs: '**coins amount**',
    callback: (message, arguments) => {

        function calcCoinSum(list) {
            return list.reduce((prev, curr) => {
                return prev + Number.parseInt(curr.coins);
            }, 0);
        }

        const channelmessage = message.client.channels.cache.get('802537184824524820')
        
        const coinsamount = arguments[0]

        function wait(miliseconds){
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, miliseconds))
        }
        //channelmessage.send(value.name + `: **${value.coins}** coins`)
        async function loop(){
            while(true){
                await wait(5000)
                if(running === 2){
                    console.log(calcCoinSum(list))
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        function arrObject(name, coins, id) {
            this.name = name
            this.coins = coins
            this.id = id
            this.listed = function(){
                return (this.name + "" +"["+this.coins+"]")
            }
        }

        const list = []

        if(message.channel.id === '802611173118705684'){
            loop()
            var user = message.author

            if(running === 0){
                console.log('Roll Started!')
                channelmessage.send('Roluette has started! Type ?rjoin (coins amount) to join!')
                list.push(new arrObject(user.username, coinsamount, user.id))
                running = 1
                setTimeout(() => {
                    running = 2
                    console.log('Roll ended')
                }, 15000);
                return
            }
            
            if(running === 1){
                list.push(new arrObject(user.username, coinsamount, user.id)) 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object` is a JS class representing a data type, use another name

Comment: I think you can get `coins` by using `arr[i][0].coins` in a loop

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti I tried it and when I console log it values appear in 2 lines instead of one

Answer (score 1):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) this should be fairly simple:

```js
function calcCoinSum(list) {
    return list.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        return prev + Number.parseInt(curr.coins);
    }, 0);
}

function arrObject(name, coins, id) {
    this.name = name
    this.coins = coins
    this.id = id
    this.listed = function () {
        return (this.name + "" + "[" + this.coins + "]")
    }
}

const list = [];
list.push(new arrObject('Mango', '19', '454214634158999514'));
list.push(new arrObject('Goodmg', '41', '721805465937021781'));

console.log('The coins sum is:', calcCoinSum(list))
```

Comment: new output in console log is: ```26 26 ```

Comment: No, with above code it will definitely output `The coins sum is: 60` - you can even try it yourself, just click "Run code snippet" ...

Comment: I added whole code, maybe something is wrong outside of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is loop through the list and then access every element of the list. Every member in the list is an object which has a value `coins` in the key. You can access that value and sum it up and store it in a variable.

```js
function calculateCoins (list) {
    int sum = 0
    for(let i of list){
        sum += parseInt(i.coins)
    }
    return sum
}
```

Comment: It also outputs me two values next to each other. Maybe it's something wrong in code?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: The ```list``` variable is actually just an array of objects like this: 
```[
  {
    name: 'Mango',
    coins: '19',
    id: '454214634158999514',
    listed: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
[
  {
    name: 'Goodmg',
    coins: '41',
    id: '721805465937021781',
    listed: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
```
Now if you pass that into the function I have given, you will get the total sum of coins.